# go to another page in applicationDidEnterBackground in iOS in device

Tags: ios, ios5, ios-simulator

In my application, When the application goes to background I am calling a Passcode page (Passcode Page which does authentication).

My **requirement** is when the user launch the app from the foreground he will see the passcode page. If he enters the correct passcode then only he can see the rest pages.

In **delegate.m file**

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
 {
   PasscodeViewController *passcodeController = [[PasscodeViewController alloc]       initWithNibName:@"PasscodeViewController" bundle:nil];

   [navController pushViewController:passcodeController animated:YES];
 }
```

When I am launching the application from the background then It is showing me the previous page( from which page I came to background ) for a fraction of second and after that Passcode page comes.

But I want to hide my confidential information from others (who doesn't know the passcode) that are shown in the previous page.

It is correctly working in Simulator but in Device it is not working properly.

Can you please guide me in that ?

**OR**

Is it the normal behavior of the iOS device ? What ever the page transition it will do, it will perform while the application is running in foreground.

I am not sure about that. Please tell me where I went wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: This could work: add the passcodeController to the root of navController, without animation, and then add on top your rootViewController. 
when application will resign, call popToRootViewControllerAnimated:

The idea is that if the passcodeController's xib is already loaded in memory, you might be able to access it in that tiny interval before the app goes offline.

Answer (score 0):

Every app I've used with a similar feature has operated as you describe, with the fractional-second flash before the lock view appears.

Comment: No idea, as I've never tried it in code, only seen it with other parties' apps. (But that's why there's no substitute for device testing!)

Answer (score 0):

Try applicationWillResignActive:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  PasscodeViewController* passcodeController = [[PasscodeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PasscodeViewController" bundle:nil];

  [navController pushViewController:passcodeController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: It is giving same experience as before. i.e. Working in simulator but not in device. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a matter of when UIKit thinks it needs to re-render... We had a similar case with a splash screen, but using `applicationDidEnterBackground` for adding the splash helped.

My idea is to avoid the animating, using

```
[navController pushViewController:passcodeController animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your app goes background add a `UIView` with white background.
Whenever your app comes up push your PasscodeViewController view on top

Please add observers for `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` and `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` to do the above functionality
Also be sure to remove the Observers when your view disappears

When user enters correct passcode remove the `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

When Application goes to background push the passcode viewcontroller to navigationcontroller in the delegate applicationDidEnterBackground because there will be that fractional flash almost all time u can have the passcodecontroller pushed before entering background.